# Wordpress & PHP to check if custom field exists, and if not replace with a random string

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a function that checks for the existence of a `post_thumbnail()` for a post in `Wordpress` and sets an element's background image appropriately. Here's what I've tried:

```
 <div class="header-cover-image" style="background-image: url(
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
      the_post_thumbnail('full');
    } else { echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/article-overlay-1.jpg' }?>
    ">
  </div>
```

This currently crashes/causes the page to render nothing at all. I'm so confused about when and where to use quotation marks when using PHP within HTML markup!

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: Missing semicolon after the else echo?

Comment: As in, `echo get_template_directory_uri(); . '/assets<etc>'}?>` ? Still doesn't render the page.

Comment: @Josh The issue seems to be with trying to add `'/assets/img/article-overlay-1.jpg'` to the template directory URI, when I remove that and add the semicolon it works fine. Ideas?

Comment: No, the problem is there is no semicolon after `xxx.jpg'`. It's echoing, concating, then hitting the end else brace, without a semicolon. It should be: `echo func() . 'string'; // semicolon`

Answer (score 1):

Try bloginfo ;

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  the_post_thumbnail('full');
} else { echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/assets/img/article-overlay-1.jpg'; }?>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with trying to echo the Wordpress function and append the string simultaneously. Fixed it by doing:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  the_post_thumbnail('full');
} else { $uri = get_template_directory_uri(); echo $uri . '/assets/img/article-overlay-1.jpg'; }?>
">
```